# How to get buy, sell and exit alerts from TradingView strategies?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

How to get buy, sell and exit alerts from TradingView strategies?

My algo trading API provider (Tratetron.tech) requires SEPERATE alerts for buy, sell and exit for its condition builder. How to get these different alerts from our own Pine Script strategies?

Secondly, there are many inbuilt Strategies listed in TradingView. How to get these different alerts from these strategies?

Answer (score 0):

There are some placeholders for alert messages as explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000531021-how-to-use-a-variable-value-in-alert/).

However, these will not be sufficient when you want to automate the trades or when you need to have specific alert messages. To handle those alerts, you need to modify the script and prepare the alert messages there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a code mentioned in the list {{strategy.order.alert_message}} but how to use it? I'm new to pine script. Further, as you mentioned what modifications are needed in the strategy script to get separate buy, sell and exit alerts? Please help.

Comment: You can use that, yes. In order to do that, you need to find `strategy.entry()`, strategy.exit()` or/and `strategy.close()` commands in the script and modify the `alert_message` property of those function calls.

Comment: Thanks. I added the codes for long entry and exit: if (longEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message="Enter Long")
if (longCloseCondition)
    strategy.close("Long", alert_message="Exit Long") But its not working. I want to get alerts for long entry, long exit, short entry and short exit in the Alert dialogue box of TradingView as the following user is getting in the drop down menu of the Alert dialogue box (Please see@ 1;50 of the video): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2BdBwF67K0&list=PL2SspAN7iWukVG1INS7-PvcxNd6BlwDWn&index=23

Comment: Still waiting for the reply....